# Document scrollheight minus height

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-browser, height

I'd like to animate scroll to the end of the page, so I need to know the position scrollheight minus height in HTML document.

I tried to `document.body.scrollHeight - screen.height`, but `document.body.scrollTop` to that value leaves a little space at the end.

How to make it exact and cross-browser? No need to support old IE.

I played with documentElement, body and window objects and their offsetHeights, availHeights etc, but still can't get correct value. I expected it to be simple, but I just can't figure it out.

In the final formula I'd like the explanation how does it work in browsers, so please do not respond like

`$(something).yourHeight()` works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `window.innerHeight`.

`screen.height` gives the height of available pixels/screen. But we need the height of viewport. So this should work:

```
document.body.scrollTop =  document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight
```

Comment: Perfect. It is explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight)